# Why aren't static local variables allowed in Java?

Tags: java

I tried using such a variable but it gave me an error which was surprising for me. Looking around for an answer as it makes no sense to me. Wanted to know if there was some security reason or something behind it....

Comment: Why would you need static local variable? What do you mean by that? Show me your code

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would defeat the purpose of `static`.

Comment: What did you tried and what error did you receive? Please provide a MCVE. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is simply a bad code style. But you may use static members. Static members can be initialized by the static {} function. But static variables can't - or might need some crazy syntax and much special effort. Or use just a member - which is almost the best way.

Comment: @devpuh - I'm not sure we need an MCVE to be able to tell the OP that static locals don't exist.

Comment: C and C++ have functions outside of classes. Java does not. Anything you could do with a static local variable in C/C++, you can do with a static class variable in Java.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes a static local variable can't exist in java, but it's possible that the asker means something else.

Answer (score 0):

Any `variable` declared within a method is supposed to be local to the method .It gets stored in the method stack in the JVM, which is one per thread . When you use `static` keyword, it indicates that this `variable` will be common for all object of the `class`

Answer (score 0):

By rule, when the static variable scope (or visible) is for the whole class, by common sense, how a local variable be declared static. A local variable scope is within the method where it is declared. If the local variable is declared static, the meaning of static is lost. If the local variable is static, the purpose of static variable is bypassed. For this reason, compiler does not allow static local variables.

[Source](https://way2java.com/oops-concepts/does-java-support-static-local-variables-inside-method/)

Comment: thanks.. yours helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

`Static` variables are instantiated at the start of program execution.

`Local` variables are instantiated when line of code inside the method that creates the variable is executed, and only last for the duration of method execution.

The keyword `static` inside of a method declaration violates the local scope and therefore is not allowed.